# How blocking search results in IBM Websphere 6.1 for google and others

Tags: search, websphere

How can blocking search results in IBM Websphere 6.1

I mean for any website like google or any search because if have testing environment so no need to appear any URL or contents related the testing in any search site

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real solution is to make your site accessible on your internal network only.  That said, most search engines respect [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/), so you could try that.  There's no specific support within the WebSphere Application Server product itself.